# Open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as disjoint unions of open intervals- can the same be said in $\mathbb{R^2}$?  Open subsets of  $\mathbb{R^2}$can be written as disjoint unions of open rectangles and  $\mathbb{R^3}$  open cuboids etc...

Comment: @Mathematician42 could you direct me to a proof please? of the $\mathbb{R^2}$ case

Comment: Oh... I think there is a proof of this in my notes :It says that in R^n the product topology(which has open sets of R crossed with open sets of R as beingthe basis for the topology) coincides with the standard topology with the usual metrics on R^n

Comment: No, I do not think this is true in $\mathbb R^n$. It being true in $\mathbb R$ is due to the fact that connex components of a subset of the real line are intervals. What is true is that open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ are (countable) unions of rectangles, balls or whatever, but this union is not disjoint.

Comment: No, that says nothing about disjointness. The result you ask about it is false in dimensions greater than 1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I'm very sorry, I completely read over the disjoint condition. Luckily other people gave him a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ denote the open unit disc in $\mathbb R^2.$ Suppose $D$ is the pairwise disjoint union of open rectangles $R_1,R_2, \dots$ Now $D$ is not an open rectangle, so at least two of these rectangles are non-empty; WLOG $R_1$ one of them. Then $R_1, (R_2 \cup R_3 \cup \cdots )$ is a separation of $D.$ That contradicts the connectedness of $D.$

In fact the only connected open subsets of $\mathbb R^n, n\ge 1,$ that are the pairwise disjoint union of open rectangles are the open rectangles themselves, by the same argument.